# Custom language for code golfs

Tags: discussion

A collegue of me just suggested, I could just invent my own language for every problem in code-golfs.

Now my question is, is it ok, if I just say I gonna invent a language for exactly this one problem and the interpreter can be found [here](http://github.com/)?

Comment: This is in the [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/17148) - things in this list are generally looked down upon and are almost always downvoted.

Comment: @kitcar2000 It doesn't belong to the standard loopholes if the language is a general-purpose language, a language that people can use for a wide range of programming problems, as Chris said in [his answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/872/9275). It would not be allowed to use your language if it is created after a challenge is posted.

Comment: @ProgramFOX "if I just say I gonna invent a language for exactly this **one problem**" implies that it is for a specific question.

Comment: @kitcar2000: Oops, I missed that. I'm sorry.